# Runnable JAR file export

Tags: java, file, export

I have a java project . I want to export it to runnable jar file.

I use eclipse to do it.

But when i run created jar file i receive `Error ~ file not found : config\file.xml` (the system cannot find the path specified).

How can I  export a folder to run success jar file at any where ?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your application is looking for a configuration file using a relative path in the file system. In order to make the jar totally self-sufficient, the code would have to be modified to look for the config file in the classpath, and the file would have to be included in the jar.

To do this, the code that opens the file must be changed to use  `Class#getResourceAsStream()` instead of using a `File` object.

Comment: It runs ok when it is in the local folder. How can i put config file in the jar?, i have edited .classpath for absolute path and reexport . The result likes before time

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need your config to be configured outside of jar, just include it in there and access with something like getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.xml") if it's located at the level of "root" package in jar

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use ant or another build system. Here is a short tutorial on ant:

http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html

Its pretty easy to create an jar file using xml in your ant build script. I have done it many times:

```
<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
```

Others may suggest maven and the like, but in reality they are all good choices. Exporting from an IDE such as eclipse really isn't a viable long term solution.

Comment: How will this help solve the actual problem, which is that the code is expecting to find a file in the filesystem?

Comment: Jim, my apologies. I should have addressed the question directly. I will make sure that I obey SO rules and not answer outside the realm of the direct question at hand.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a config-folder in your projects directory, and there is a file you want to read from, you have to copy this folder to the directory of your jar-file too

Comment: Yes, I know and i tried it.It's Ok. But i want to have only jar-file and use it in any where without config folder . Can i export config folder into jar-file ? thanks